# Unrecognized field at: database Dropwizard/Java 8

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am trying to use docker to run a server using dropwizard and a mysql database. I followed the tutorial and believe added the necessary files but still I am still getting the following error. https://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/jdbi.html. When trying to run docker-compose up. This also happens when I try and run the following in my terminal too. `java -jar target/bitly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server src/config.yml`

```
server_1   | config.yml has an error:
server_1   |   * Unrecognized field at: database
server_1   |     Did you mean?:
server_1   |       - template
server_1   |       - metrics
server_1   |       - defaultName
server_1   |       - server
server_1   |       - logging
server_1   |
```

I've been through most of the related problems on stackoverflow but cannot seem to figure out why this error is happening in my config.yml file.

I have the full repo here. 
https://github.com/Jazilch/bit.ly

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you use version 0.7.1 of Dropwizard? The current version is 1.3.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue needing immediate attention is this:
https://github.com/Jazilch/bit.ly/blob/1b4f8e77acced6e054cced5bf4cdf51d2d7da2fc/server/pom.xml#L16-L29

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0-rc1</version>
```

You are using several different versions of the various `dropwizard` modules. They are not meant to be interchangeable. Always use only one.

Also you could remove the dependency about `<artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>`. The `dropwizard-jdbi` is declaring and including it: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/3df1e0a621a2b6f1f559fa95029abe09ce41e093/dropwizard-jdbi/pom.xml#L29

Comment: This worked for me. I removed the dropwizard-db dependency and make sure to use the same version for dropwizard-jdbi.